# how to prevent a running spring boot application from going down when kafka broker becomes unavailable?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

My spring boot 2.1.5 consumer application goes down with below exception when Kafka broker becomes unavailable. It is using spring-kafka 2.2.6. I need my application to stay up and resume consuming when kafka broker is back.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean
'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry';
nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

I have tried @KafkaListener with `autostartup=false` and used CommandLineRunner to get around it , with that application doesn't go down but then it does not consume messages when broker is back until restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the container property `misssingTopicsFatal` to `false` to prevent an attempt to connect to the broker during initialization. It is now `false` by default (in version 2.3.4 and later).

You can start an `autoStartup=false` container using the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean - give the listener an `id` and use it to get a reference to the container from the registry.

Comment: This for sure allowing to start the application and keep trying to connect but i have not been able to test if it can resume consuming when broker is up as my local kafka is messed up. I should be able to try that soon. Thanks Gary.

Comment: just to update here that i was able to test and everything worked as expected . Thanks again.